# CORS POST not working with Apache on FF

Tags: ajax, tomcat, cors

I'm trying to do a CORS POST call from Firefox to my Tomcat server. The Tomcat provides RESTful service. Here is my server-side return code:

```
        ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok( JSON.serialize(result));

        rb.header("Content-Type", "text/javascript;charset=utf8");
        rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        rb.header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3628800");
        rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST");

        return rb.build();
```

And this is my AJAX call:

```
var feedQueryPOST = {"param" : someListOfParams, "timeWindow": 36000};

     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/MyWebService/getwebfeed",
        contentType: "text/plain",
        data: feedQueryPOST,
        async: true,
        success:function(json){
            alert("success!");
        },
        error:function(e){
            alert(JSON.stringify(e));
        },
     });
```

When I do a test query, I use RESTClient to inspect the header and it comes back as:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800
Content-Length: 318
Content-Type: text/javascript;charset=utf8
Date: Mon, 31 Dec 2012 12:02:11 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

But on my javascript end the callback is still going to Error with readystate = 0 and status = 0. I've been looking around for answers for a very long time to no avail. I know I might be missing something simple here. Any help is appreciated, thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Try setting `rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `contentType: "text/plain",`, use `dataType: 'json'` and you should be fine